# Replace space with dash (-) in url only

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is it possible to change the space in the url to a dash (-) without changing it in the code?

The URL is used to identify the page, so it is not possible to just change the url because the page will not be found anymore so `str_replace` is not usable in this solution.

Using `str_replace` twice, once to change the space to dash and on the page-loader to change it back to spaces isn't going to work either, some pages already have a dash in the pagename :)

I was hoping this could be achived with htaccess but I have no idea how.
Is it possible with htacces to show a different url in the browser then the actual url?

For example: `www.example.com/pages/hello%20world`
should be visable as `www.example.com/pages/hello-world` but the `GET` variable should still be `hello%20world`.

This is my current .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+home/httpd/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/View/Products/([^%20]*)%20([^\s]*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/home/httpd/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/View/Products/%1-%2 [L,NE,R]
    RewriteRule "^(/home/httpd/vhosts/domain.nl/httpdocs/app/View/Products/)/([^-]*)-+(.*)$" "/$1/$2 $3" [L,NE,NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Example url to one of the products = http://www.example.nl/software/category/details/this%20is%20a%20product-name

Comment: Show some code, expand a bit more on where you're replacing what data... where is it comming from, how are you passing it to what, and why, who, where... ?

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+path/([^%20]*)%20([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /path/%1-%2 [L,NE,R]

RewriteRule "^(path)/([^-]*)-+(.*)$" "/$1/$2 $3" [L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: To bad: Didn't do a thing

Comment: I am clicking on a link that contains the spaces and my goal is to replace them with dashes. Without changing the GET variable

Comment: Yes it won't change. 1. Make sure these are the first rule. 2. Make sure to replace `/path/` with actual path of your pages. 3. I tested these rules and they work fine.

Comment: changed the question with my current htaccess file. It is still not working

Comment: What is your full URL with spaces originally?

Comment: Your .htaccess definitely needs fix but before that I need to know your full URL for `products` which has spaces.