# Replace spaces with hyphen (-) on .htaccess without changing the variable on GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo, clean-urls

I want to replace the spaces with hyphen on url to be seo-friendly but without changing the GET variable . 
my current url is like

```
http://www.website.com/Apple%20Inc/iPad%20Air/
```

And the .htaccess i am using is  this

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ mobile.php?brand=$1&mobile=$2 [L]
```

I want to have a url like

```
http://www.website.com/Apple-Inc/iPad-Air/
```

but keep the variables i want to retrieve with GET must be

```
Apple%20Inc
```

and

```
iPad%20Air
```

Is there any solution to make this without changing the variable on GET?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @anubhava  This will not work. I don't want to change the variable.

Comment: @anubhava the variable will be changed  if for example the variable $mobile=GT-I500 . If i replace it with space the variable will be destroyed.

Comment: There is no magic in rewrite rules. Same hyphen to space replacement issue will be there in rules also.

Comment: @anubhava i found this answer here . You have posted the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216358/replace-space-with-dash-in-url-only . How can implement this methods to my solution ? Thanks for the help

Comment: No that will also convert `mobile=GT-I500` to `mobile=GT I500`

Comment: @anubhava Got it..Thank you very much for your help..i will try to find other method to fix this ...